Suspicion of Arzela's theorem in "Topology: A Categorical Approach"
Now I'm reading "Topology: A Categorical Approach". I suspect that the statment of Arzela's theorem in the book is wrong. (Its proof is omitted in the book.)

Arzela’s Theorem: Let $X$ be compact, $(Y,d)$ be a metric space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence
of functions in $\mathbf{Top}(X,Y)$. If $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous and if for each $x\in X$ the set $\{f_nx\}$ is bounded, then $\{f_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly.

If $Y=\mathbb{R}$, the theorem is true because boundedness implies relative compactness. But it doesn't in general e.g. normed spaces of infinite dimension.

Maybe it should say that for each $x \in X$, the set ${ f_n(x) : n \geq 1 }$ is relatively compact, rather than just bounded?

@ThusleGadelankz I think so. Relative compactness is sufficient.

I found a counterexample. Define $f_n\colon \{0\}\to \ell^{\infty}$ as $f_n(0)=(\delta_{nm})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$. $\{f_n\}$ has no subsequences which converge.
